# How to fit a (gaussian) mixture model to a dataset with (right) censored data in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, mixture-distribution, censoring

I am trying to fit a mixture distribution to a dataset in R. Exploiting the R package [mixtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/mixtools.pdf), this goes pretty well. However, up to 20% of the data point in the dataset are right censored, therefore the 'normalmixEM' function performs not as accurate as I would like (it underestimates the distribution).

So, in order to fix this, I am looking for a way/R package to fit a mixture model to a dataset with (right) censored data in R.
I found the [CensMixReg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CensMixReg/CensMixReg.pdf) package, that uses a multivariate Student-t distribution to fit mixture models of censored data ([Lachos *et al.*](https://www.ime.unicamp.br/sites/default/files/rp15_2016.pdf)). However, simply entering the following code:

```
CensMmix(y=as.matrix(vector of datapoint), cc = [vector of censoring status])

Error in Cens.MmixEM(cc, y, nu, mu, Sigma, pii, g, get.init, criteria,  : 
  The model is not specified correctly.
```

or

```
CensMmix(y=as.matrix(vector of datapoint), cc = [vector of censoring status], g = [amount of components, e.g. 3)
Error in cc[j, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

does not seem to work and I do not understand why.

Two questions:

1) Is the CensMixReg package a proper way to fit a mixture model to a dataset with right censored data?

2) What should I add/alter to the code above for the package to work?

Any other suggestions for a solution are of course also welcome!